# Facebook login fails on iPhone 4 and Emulator

Tags: ios, facebook, authentication

I used the Facebook SDK 3.5.1 to intergrate facebook in my iOS app.

When I run it on my iPhone 5 (iOS 6.1.2 no Jailbreak), no problem everything works just fine.

When I run it on my dads iPhone 4 (iOS 6.1.4 no Jailbreak) there are some issues.
When I press the login button the app shows an alert "AppName would like to access your basic info and list of friend", when I press ok nothing happens(on my iPhone 5 it logs in after this alert). When I press the login button again, the same alert pops up and it all start over again.

In my emulator (iOS 6.1) I experience the exact same problem. If i disable the facebook login in the settings of my emulator it shows a popup with login fields instead of the alertbox.

In this case my emulator logs the following:
FBSDKLog: Cannot use the Facebook app or Safari to authorize, BLOCKED_OUT is not registered as a URL Scheme

I read that this may occured because no facebook app is installed on the emulator. But even with this kind of login it does not work.

I used the exact same code as on this page on facebook:
https://developers.facebook.com/ios/login-ui-control/

```
FBLoginView *loginView = [[FBLoginView alloc] init];

    loginView.delegate = self;
    // Align the button in the center horizontally
    loginView.frame = CGRectMake((self.view.center.x - (loginView.frame.size.width / 2)), 150, loginView.frame.size.width, loginView.frame.size.height);
    [self.view addSubview:loginView];
    [loginView sizeToFit];
```

Can anyone help me?

Update:

I implemented the following method, after I press the login button and I grant my app access it tells me that the user cancels te login.

```
- (void)loginView:(FBLoginView *)loginView 
        handleError:(NSError *)error {
    NSString *alertMessage, *alertTitle;
    if (error.fberrorShouldNotifyUser) {
        // If the SDK has a message for the user, surface it. This conveniently
        // handles cases like password change or iOS6 app slider state.
        alertTitle = @"Facebook Error";
        alertMessage = error.fberrorUserMessage;
    } else if (error.fberrorCategory == FBErrorCategoryAuthenticationReopenSession) {
        // It is important to handle session closures since they can happen 
        // outside of the app. You can inspect the error for more context 
        // but this sample generically notifies the user.
        alertTitle = @"Session Error";
        alertMessage = @"Your current session is no longer valid. Please log in again.";
    } else if (error.fberrorCategory == FBErrorCategoryUserCancelled) {
        // The user has cancelled a login. You can inspect the error
        // for more context. For this sample, we will simply ignore it.
        NSLog(@"user cancelled login");
    } else {
        // For simplicity, this sample treats other errors blindly.
        alertTitle  = @"Unknown Error";
        alertMessage = @"Error. Please try again later.";
        NSLog(@"Unexpected error:%@", error);
    }

    if (alertMessage) {
        [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:alertTitle
                                    message:alertMessage
                                   delegate:nil
                          cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                          otherButtonTitles:nil] show];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you also asking for additional permissions in addition to basic login?

I experienced a similar issue when trying to request the `publish_actions` permission. Once I removed this permissions, it started working again.

Also, on the iPhone itself, if you have the Facebook App installed on the iPhone, make sure your application is allowed to connect using it. Go to Settings > Facebook and make sure your app is enabled for Login.

Also, make sure the application isn't in "Sandbox" mode. If you are in sandbox mode, create a test user account to test the application.

Comment: Hey, Thx for the answer. I didn't define permissions by myself, because it wasn't necessary when testing on my iPhone 5. I can try defining them manually. The only things I use it for is, getting a list of friends and login for receiving my own userid.

Comment: Hi, I tried defining them manually but still the same problem, any ideas?

Comment: If you have the Facebook App installed on the iPhone, make sure your application is allowed to connect using it. Go to Settings > Facebook and make sure your app is enabled for Login.

Comment: The Emulator doesn't have a Facebook app. My emulator is running iOS 6.1 so it has Facebook integration. When I check the settings my app is missing. After login is successful it will be added here but login isn't successful. But when I disable the facebook login in settings it popsup a webpage with facebook login. But even this one isn't working. On the iPhone 4 it doesn't show up in settings as well. I'm clueless :(

Comment: Hi, I've tried some things, but unfortunately I wasn't be able to solve my problem yet. I updated my question, after implementing a delegate method of the facebook login it tells met that the user canceled the login. But the user(me) did not, the alert box has two options "Do not allow" and "Ok", no matter wich one I choose it tells me that login is cancelled. So even by pressing "OK" it's cancelled. Same for the login popup instead of the iOS 6 way.

Comment: I logged in with a different facebook user, so I had to give this user permission to use my app because it's a development app.

Comment: Hi Jasper, this is very helpful -- perhaps you could put it up as the answer somewhere, otherwise someone like me has to read through all of these comments, and may just leave because the question appears to lack a successful answer!